# Error in indval (labdsv) in R - "All species must occur in at least one plot"

Tags: r, statistics, cluster-analysis, analysis, indicator

I ran the following Indicator Species Analysis (indval) code from labdsv package in R on a dataframe called "data" where species abundances are columns and sites are rows as below:

```
     Site    Species X  Species Y  Species Z etc
     1       10         3          5
     2       5          15         220
     3       0          1          0
     4       21         100        3
```

In a separate file is the corresponding Group data for each site which is either group 1 or group 2 (called this spe.grp), that is the following:

```
    Groups 
    1
    2
    1
    2
```

I removed categorical variables so that spe.only has only the species data

```
   spe.only <- data[,2:1521]
```

I then removed species which do not occur in any sample

```
   spe.only[, (!apply(spe.only==0,2,all))]
```

I then ran Indicator species based on Groups (1) or (2)

```
  (iva <- indval(spe.only, spe.grp$Groups))
```

But I get

> "Error in indval.default(spe.only, spe.grp$Status) :    All species
> must occur in at least one plot"

How do I resolve this error so that I can run indval correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The step

```
spe.only[, (!apply(spe.only==0,2,all))]
```

was not assigned back to the original object  i.e. if we don't assign it back it, the output from the above step only prints on the console and not updates the original object

```
spe.only <- spe.only[, (!apply(spe.only==0,2,all))]
```

Now do the `indval`

```
> library(labdsv)
> indval(spe.only, spe.grp$Groups)
$relfrq
           1 2
SpeciesX 0.5 1
SpeciesY 1.0 1
SpeciesZ 0.5 1

$relabu
                  1         2
SpeciesX 0.27777778 0.7222222
SpeciesY 0.03361345 0.9663866
SpeciesZ 0.02192982 0.9780702

$indval
                  1         2
SpeciesX 0.13888889 0.7222222
SpeciesY 0.03361345 0.9663866
SpeciesZ 0.01096491 0.9780702

$maxcls
SpeciesX SpeciesY SpeciesZ 
       2        2        2 

$indcls
 SpeciesX  SpeciesY  SpeciesZ 
0.7222222 0.9663866 0.9780702 

$pval
SpeciesX SpeciesY SpeciesZ 
   0.678    0.319    0.671
```

---

The error is reproducible on the original 'spe.only' object

```
> indval(spe.only, spe.grp$Groups)
Error in indval.default(spe.only, spe.grp$Groups) : 
  All species must occur in at least one plot
```

#### data

```
 
spe.only <- structure(list(SpeciesX = c(10L, 5L, 0L, 21L), SpeciesY = c(3L, 
15L, 1L, 100L), SpeciesZ = c(5L, 220L, 0L, 3L), SpeciesD = c(0, 
0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

spe.grp <- structure(list(Groups = c(1, 2, 1, 2)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```